# How do I replace hyphen (-) with space in a string except for the matched pattern in a string?

Tags: python, regex

I have strings similar to

```
text='Studied b-tech from college in 2010-13'
```

Using

```
text.replace('-', ' ')
```

will produce

```
Studied b tech from college in 2010 13
```

But what I want is:

```
Studied b tech from college in 2010-13
```

I have prepared below pattern for grepping tokens like `2010-13`, but how do I use it in my code?

```
regex_pattern='(\d{4}-\d{2,4})'
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: Could you do `text.replace('b-tech','b tech ') `? Or is there more input you need to replace?  Like everything but 2010-13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to describe the two possibilities for your hyphen using negative lookarounds:

- not preceded by four digits: `(?<!\b[0-9]{4})`
- not followed by two or four digits: `(?![0-9]{2}(?:[0-9]{2})?\b)`

( *"not preceded by A **or** not followed by B"* is the negation of *"preceded by A **and** followed by B"* )

example:

```
import re

text = 'Studied b-tech from college in 2010-13'

result = re.sub(r'-(?:(?<!\b[0-9]{4}-)|(?![0-9]{2}(?:[0-9]{2})?\b))', ' ', text)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/OXGW5j/1)

*( writing `- (?: (?<! ... - ) | (?! ... ) )` is more efficient than `(?<! ... )-|-(?! ... )`, that's why you retrieve the hyphen in the lookbehind )*

Comment: I think this is the most robust answer. One question though. `(?<!\d{4})-(?!\d{2})` This expression seems to give you the same answer, but it's closer to the option that you say is less efficient. Could you elaborate on why this is less efficient? My regex is very naive.

Comment: @rwhitt2049: `(?<!\d{4})-(?!\d{2})` is wrong because it doesn't match something like `abc-12` or `1234-abc` or `12345-6789`. About why `-(?:(?<!A-)|(?!B))` is more efficient than `(?<!A)-|-(?!B)`: the first way quickly discards positions that are not a `-` when the second need to test `(?<!A)` even for positions that are not a `-` (and in this case the second branch is also tested and will fail on `-`). Also, in general, patterns that start with an alternation are slower.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "Studied b-tech from college in 2010-13"

>>> re.sub("\-([a-zA-Z]+)", r"\1", text)
"Studied btech from college in 2010-13"
```

`[a-zA-Z]` will not match with a number coming after `-`. You can find more about `re.sub` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub).

Comment: This is the correct answer. I thought `.replace()` would work but with the conditional, it gets too crazy.

Answer (score 0):

There is third optional argument for `replace` that allows you to denote which instance you'd like to replace.

```
text.replace('-',' ', 1)
```

Comment: Would this still work if the string was: 

`text='Studied in 2010-13 b-tech from college`

Comment: I assume you mean `text='Studied b-tech from college in 2010-13 at B-college'` ? If so, no it will not still work. You've changed your requirements, please update your original question.

Comment: This is not my question :) I'm just thinking that if the OP wants a way to remove ALL instances of the hyphen that are not for dates, there should be a better way than replacing the first instance.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't initially notice you were not the original poster. That is correct, the `replace` above is only for the first instance and assumes the date is not first. He would need a regex for more instances but ignore the date. OP did not specify if the order would change.

Comment: No problem :) I think @Ozgur has the perfect answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Python's string `replace` takes a `max` argument meaning the maximum number of occurrences to replace.

If you want just the 1st use `text.replace(*, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

I would use Python's `.replace()` over the regex here.

Something like:

`str.replace(old, new[, max])`

where `max` is the number of instances you would want to replace. If you just want to replace the hyphen of non-number strings though, I would go with something similar to this question: [How do I check if a string is a number (float) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float-in-python) instead changing it to catch if the characters next to the hyphen are numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to match the anti-pattern

regex:   `(\d{0,3}(?:\D|^)\d{0,3})-(\d?(?:\D|$)\d?)`
replace: `$1 $2`